# real time sum with two input radio button and href using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, sum, real-time

I want to summing 2 input from button and href. this is code that I have

this is HTML CODE

```
  <a id="add1" class="thumbnail"  alt="100000" href="">one</a>
    <br>
  <a id="add1" class="thumbnail"  alt="150000" href="">two</a>
    <br>
  <a id="add1" class="thumbnail"  alt="90000" href="">theree</a>

<hr>
<hr>
<input class="add2" type="radio" value="1" alt="100000" name="material">
LACE
<br>
<input class="add2" type="radio" value="2" alt="200000" name="material">
LACE - LEATHER
<br>
<input class="add2" type="radio" value="3" alt="150000" name="material">
LACE - SUEDE
<br>
<hr>
<hr>
<img src="" alt="0" id="mainImage" class="pret">
<div id="cau"  alt="0"class="pret"></div>
<div id="usertotal"> PRICE  :  IDR  0</div>
```

this is Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.thumbnail').live("click", function() {
            var g = $(this).attr('alt');
            var e = $(this).attr('href');
            calculateSum();
            $('#mainImage').hide();
            $('#mainImage').html('<img class="pret" alt="'+g+'" src="'+e+'">').fadeIn();
            return false; 
        });

        $('.add2:checked').change(function(){ 
            var m = $(this).attr('alt');
            var a = $(this).attr('value');
            alert(m);
            calculateSum();
            $('#cau').hide();
            $('#cau').html('<div name="'+a+'" class="pret" alt="'+m+'"></div>').fadeIn();
            return false; 
        });

    });
    function calculateSum() {
        var sum = 0;
        $(".pret").each(function() {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).attr('alt'));
        });
        $('#usertotal').html('PRICE : IDR  '+ sum);
    }
</script>
```

the question is : why is my code running so slow? I must click 2 time to summing it? I want it's running on 1  click.

thanks for answering :)
Regards

Comment: Your first invocation of `calculateSum` is useless: you have only one HTML element having class `pret` at this moment, thus `calculateSum` gives you `0`. You add `<img class="pret" .../>` AFTER that invocation, not before.

Answer (score 1):

I see numerous issues with your code, so I have no idea what is actually causing your problem.

First off: You need a space between your alt attribute and your class attribute, as such:

```
<div id="cau" alt="0" class="pret"></div>
```

Secondly:

```
$('#mainImage').html('<img class="pret" alt="'+g+'" src="'+e+'">').fadeIn();
```

This should not even work correctly, because you can't put html "inside" an image element (`#mainImage` is an `<img />` element after all).

Thirdly:

```
$('.add2:checked').change(function(){
```

This should not do anything to the code you posted, because there are no elements with class `.add2` that are checked on page load.  Therefore, this handler will never do anything.

Comment: hi steve thanks for answering 

for no 1 and 2 i've fixed it. and it's working. but to get value I still must to click it twice. because I put it on class="pret" before summing it. do u have an idea for it? 

for no 3. can you give me the correct method to get a value from radio-button?